# How and in what order do I combine printf formatting arguments for a single printed output consisting of Strings and doubles?

Tags: java, printf

Good afternoon,

Here are three lines of java code that I would like to combine into a single printf statement. The idea is to eventually have several columns of evenly spaced data expressed in computer scientific notation with 5 significant digits. I can't seem to combine the arguments in the right order. Also, when I try to format multiple columns by adding extra "%-#s" formats, I am being told that I have not included enough arguments, or funny stuff comes out. What am I doing wrong?

```
System.out.printf("%-3s", "a_"+k+" = ");
System.out.printf("%6.3e\n", a_k[k]);
System.out.printf("%6.3e\n", a1_k[k]);
```

I have tried the below in various orders and combinations to no avail, and can't understand the javadocs on how to implement this correctly:

```
System.out.printf("%-3s%5.4e%-10s%5.4e\n", "a_"+k+" = ", a_k[k], a1_k[k]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I see four `%`, but you only have three values

Comment: Could you tell us what the expected format should look like?

Comment: I do not know what documentation you are referring to, but simply put. Don't to the fancy formatting until you actual get your data printed. For example , you currently have `"%s %e %s %e"`, so (string, exponent, string, exponent). Where is the fourth data point? You have `"a_"+k+" = ", a_k[k], a1_k[k]`, which is **three** values

Comment: Like @cricket_007 stated, you need another string. If you think it's required for padding, then you can add in an empty string or one with a new line. "" or "\n". Something like "a_"+k+" = ", a_k[k], "\n", a1_k[k]

Comment: @Brion format would look like: a1:   column1e-10     column2e-14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I try to format multiple columns by adding extra "%-#s" formats, I am being told that I have not included enough arguments

It is expecting a string argument between `a_k[k]` and `a1_k[k]`.

Here are the four formats I assume you were wanting.

1. `%-3s` -> `"a_" + k + "= "`
2. `%5.4e` -> `a_k[k]`
3. `%-10s` -> (whitespace)
4. `%5.4e` -> `a1_k[k]`

Therefore, just insert a `""` for position 3

```
System.out.printf("%-3s%5.4e%-10s%5.4e\n", "a_"+k+" = ", a_k[k], "", a1_k[k]);
```

[See example](http://ideone.com/MduFlL)

Or, to make this easier on the eyes

```
String akEq = "a_"+k+" = ";
float col1 = a_k[k];
float col2 = a1_k[k];
System.out.printf("%-3s%5.4e%-10s%5.4e\n", akEq, col1, "", col2);
```

And, going further, put `"a_%d = "` into the format as well instead of using string concatenation

```
System.out.printf("a_%d = %5.4e%-10s%5.4e\n", k, col1, "", col2);
```

Comment: Why not go farther and replace the concatenation of `"a_"+k+" = ";` by changing the format string?

Comment: Could. Wasn't part of the question, though

Comment: Fair enough. I'll let this stand as a comment unless you want to incorporate it into your answer.

Comment: I mean, the `%-3s` has padding for some reason, so I suppose that's one reason to leave it out

Comment: This did the trick fairly nicely. However, I noticed that there is some misalignment, probably due to that empty " ". Can I apply both the -10 alignment/spacing and the 5.4e to a single argument? Either way, thank you this was more than enough.

Comment: Not sure I can really help with the formatting. If you have another question, though, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Regarding your comment on the other answer, see about [link-only answers](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259)